# how to project elasticsearch document in certain way?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have several products documents in elasticsearch along with selling store details.
for example:

```
[
    {
        "name": "colgate toothpaste",
        "store_name": "khan market",
        "location": 28.618822,77.2078499
    },
    {
        "name": "closeup toothpaste",
        "store_name": "khan market",
        "location": 28.618822,77.2078499
    },
    {
        "name": "closeup toothpaste",
        "store_name": "punjabi kirana",
        "location": 28.6186054,77.20947
    },
    {
        "name": "colgate toothpaste",
        "store_name": "punjabi kirana",
        "location": 28.6186054,77.20947
    },
    {
        "name": "colgate toothpaste",
        "store_name": "shivashakti store",
        "location": 13.0690595,80.1878027
    }
]
```

Now i want to fetch all products serviceable at a particular location (within 10 km radius). and group all stores by products in search results.
for search query

```
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "query": "toothpaste"
        }
    }
}
```

for a person in delhi result should look like

```
[
{
    "name": "colgate toothpaste",
    "stores": [
        {
            "store_name": "khan market",
            "location": 28.618822,77.2078499
        }.
        {
            "store_name": "punjabi kirana",
            "location": 28.6186054,77.20947
        }
    ]
},
{
    "name": "closeup toothpaste",
    "stores": [
        {
            "store_name": "khan market",
            "location": 28.618822,77.2078499
        }.
        {
            "store_name": "punjabi kirana",
            "location": 28.6186054,77.20947
        }
    ]
}
]
```

while for person at chennai it will look like

```
{
    "name": "colgate toothpaste",
    "stores": [
        {
            "store_name": "shivashakti store",
            "location": 13.0690595,80.1878027
        }
    ]
}
```

can someone suggest how to acheive that?

Comment: "serviceable at a particular location" - What is the criteria for serviceability?

Comment: within x km distance from shoppers location.